# Can't use css pseudo :before on class of ASP.NET Custom Web Control

Tags: asp.net, css, custom-controls, pseudo-element

I've got a problem with the style of my custom web control.
I am trying to create a fancy button control to use in my future projects.

I started by creating some HTML-file where i have the folowing html.
        `<a class="button">Home</a>`

And the css:

```
.button:before{
...
}
```

This file works great, the css is used properly and thanks to the :before pseudo in my css file I have a nice extra box around my button.

Now that I was sure that the style worked i wanted to create a web control in ASP.Net
So I created one, here is some code-sample.

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.ID);
        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CssClass) ? "button" : this.CssClass);          

        if (this.Style.Count>0)
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Style, this.Style.ToString());
        if(this.Width != default(Unit))
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, this.Width.ToString());
        if (this.Height != default(Unit))
        output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Height, this.Height.ToString());

        output.RenderBeginTag("a");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageSrc))
        {
            output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Style, String.Format("background: url('{0}') no-repeat {1}px {2}px;",ImageSrc,ImageXPos, ImageYPos));
            output.RenderBeginTag("div");
            output.RenderEndTag();
        }
        output.Write(Text);
        output.RenderEndTag();
    }
```

The html generated is the same as in my test file. but for some reason the :before css isn't applied. Can anybody help me solving this problem?

*My testfile was pure html but when i put the pure html code into my asp.net site it also doesn't apply the :before style*

This is a small Fiddle example where you can't see the error because it ain't ASP.net
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Beejee/9tb69/2/)

SOLVED:
Seems like the problem is with the z-index.
atm it is -2 which means it is displayed behind all the other content of the page.
My bad

Comment: Do you have a live link that we could see the final output and test output? Possibly create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for both - it might even help you answer the question yourself.

Comment: I added a fiddle but don't think you can do anything with it :p

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is with the z-index.
atm it is -2 is displayed behind all the other content of the page.
My bad